# Trying to upload to App Store with an account associated to two teams

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I've been recently added as user of a second Apple Developers Program. When I sign in Apple Member Center, I'm told to select the team I want to sign in with, and in Xcode's preferences I can see both teams in my account.

However, after archiving an app and choosing one of the teams, Xcode says:

> No accounts with iTunes Connect access. iTunes Connect access for "TEAM" is required. Add an account in the Accounts preference pane.

As I said, I already have such account with both teams. I also can access iTunes Connect with the team I want via Safari.

Is somebody else experiencing this?

Thanks

**EDIT:** When accessing iTunes Connect via web browser, I'm not asked to select a team...

Comment: Is your login email in iTC the same as in Apple Developer?

Comment: Yes, it is, in fact I access with my former team, I'm not asked to select one...

Comment: Until last week it was not possible to have the same appleId within for 2 iTunes Connect teams. I suspect you have been added to the developer Team but not to itunes connect which has to been done separately